Are there other methods to list the coprime arrays within the array?
The list array is:
list = Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}]

get the list is:
{{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {2, 5}, {2, 6}, {2, 7}, {2, 8}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 
  6}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 6}, {4, 7}, {4, 8}, {5, 6}, {5, 
  7}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {6, 8}, {7, 8}}

How to pick out all the coprime arrays as follows from it?
{{2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {4, 
  7}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}

My personal approach is like this, and it achieves the goal! Are there any other methods?
list = Subsets[Range[2, 8], {2}]
coprimelist = Select[list, GCD @@ # == 1 &]

the result is:


Or Select[list, CoprimeQ @@ # &]

Possible duplicate of Select coprimes from list of pairs

Pick[list, CoprimeQ @@@ list]


{{2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {4,
7}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}

Cases[list, x_ /; CoprimeQ @@ x]

list /. {a_, b_} /; ! CoprimeQ[a, b] :> Nothing

Catenate @ SequenceSplit[list, {x_} /; ! CoprimeQ @@ x]


same result


For something different:
List @@@ (RelationGraph[CoprimeQ, Range[2, 8]] // EdgeList)

yields: {{2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 7}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {4, 5}, {4,
7}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {6, 7}, {7, 8}}
